# Всем привет) total += arr; Почему не работает? Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'int', 'int[]'

Tags: java

Вот мой код)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String start;
        String exit;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter start interval");
        start = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter exit interval");
        exit = scanner.nextLine();
        for (int i = Integer.parseInt(start); i <= Integer.parseInt(exit); i++) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                int[] arr = new int[i];
                int total = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    total += arr;
                }

            }
//                else if (i % 2 == 0){
//                    System.out.println("Пар" + i);
//                }


        }
    }
```

Вот задача

- Пользователь вводит интервал (например, [1, 12]).
- Программа выводит на экран нечетные числа из интервала по
  ростом и парные числа по убыванию.
- Програма виводить на екран суму непарних та парних чисел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`total += arr` означает, что вы пытаетесь к числу прибавить массив.

`total += arr[j]` а так мы к числу прибавляем элемент из массива под индексом `j`.

Comment: Спасибо но у меня все равно не выводит сумму чисел(total) я что-то не так сделал